# Python PyQt5 Combobox Connection Inside Loop

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to loop through all combo-boxes and set respective labels based on the combo-box selection.  I can brute force the code by setting up a function for each connection but would prefer not to if it isn't necessary.  I have three boxes (`self.boxes`) and three labels (`self.units`) that I'm trying to update element 1 with 1, 2 with 2, and 3 with 3; however, my code is resulting in the selection of each box applying only to the 3rd label.  The following is an abbreviated version of my current code:

```
import basic_GUI as gui    # basic_GUI.py is the auto-generated pyuic5 file
class MainUiClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, gui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(MainUiClass, self).__init__(parent)
      self.setupUi(self)


      # Initialize variables
      self.box = None
      self.unit = None
      self.DDitems = ['Dew Point','Mass Mixing Ratio','Relative Humidity']  # combobox listed items
      self.boxes = [self.HumGenDDbox1, self.HumGenDDbox2, self.HumGenDDbox3]  # comboboxes
      self.units = [self.HumGenUnits1, self.HumGenUnits2, self.HumGenUnits3]  # labels

      self.addDDOptions()   # add options to dropdown boxes
      self.updateDDBoxes()  # update labels for dropdown boxes

    def addDDOptions(self):
      for box in self.boxes:
        box.addItems(self.DDitems)

    def updateDDBoxes(self):
      for self.box, self.unit in zip(self.boxes, self.units):
        self.box.activated[str].connect(self.updateUnits)

    def updateUnits(self, text):
      if text == 'Dew Point':
        self.unit.setText('°F')
      elif text == 'Mass Mixing Ratio':
        self.unit.setText('kgH2O/kgAir')
      elif text == 'Relative Humidity':
        self.unit.setText('%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you are assigning `self.box` and `self.unit` within the for cycle, which not only is wrong, but results in the *final* box and unit objects of the cycle being assigned to those attribute names.

To keep a reference to the widgets and ensure that the function updates the correct one, a possibility is to use a lambda for the connection *with the **target widget** as a **keyword argument***, otherwise it will always point to the last object the for cycle assigns to the variable.

```
    def updateDDBoxes(self):
        # this will not work as expected, since "unit" will always refer to
        # the last object yielded in the for loop
        #
        # for box, unit in zip(self.boxes, self.units):
        #     box.activated[str].connect(lambda text: self.updateUnits(text, unit))

        # this ensures that the "unit" object is the correct one
        for box, unit in zip(self.boxes, self.units):
            box.activated[str].connect(
                lambda text, unit=unit: self.updateUnits(text, unit))

    def updateUnits(self, text, unit):
        if text == 'Dew Point':
            unit.setText('°F')
        elif text == 'Mass Mixing Ratio':
            unit.setText('kgH2O/kgAir')
        elif text == 'Relative Humidity':
            unit.setText('%')
```